# Reading the output of profvis in R

Tags: r, profiling, flamegraph

I am trying to learn to use profvis. Here is a link with a reproducible example:

[profvis example](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/)

I am not able to see why there are TWO numbers for Memory ie. -3.5 and 9.5 (where Time = 1290) in the first example in this page.

Can someone explain how to interpret the 2 numbers for Memory?

Answer (score 0):

**The positive numbers are allocated memory and the negative numbers are deallocated memory** (between the previous and current sample).

From the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/):

> Memory: Memory allocated or deallocated (for negative numbers) for a
>   given call stack. This is represented in megabytes and aggregated over
>   all the call stacks over the code in the given row

Also note that

> Interpreting this information can be a little tricky, because it does
>   not necessarily reflect memory allocated and deallcated at that line
>   of code. The sampling profiler records information about memory
>   allocations that happen between the previous sample and the current
>   one. This means that the allocation/deallocation values on that line
>   may have actually occurred in a previous line of code.

Comment: So a number to the left of the line in memory will always be negative (corresponding to deallocation) and a number on the right of the line will always be positive (corresponding to allocation)? Suppose I need to compute the maximum possible memory used by a program at any point in time to determine hardware(RAM) requirements for the program. An upper bound on the memory used by the code will be =  max ( positive - negative  numbers ) in each line because we may have allocation BEFORE deallocation. Is that correct? Can I not compute the precise maximum amount of RAM used by a program?

Comment: I now think the maximum amount of RAM used at any point in the code will = max(a_i + b_i + a_j, here b_i is negative since it is a deallocation) where a_i's are the allocations and b_i's are deallocations, where i and j are successive (not  necessarily in consecutive lines) allocations / deallocations.

Comment: That should be the case, yes.

Comment: Is there a software which can do this computation for a big file where manual work is a little tough ?

Comment: Please see the [profmem](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/index.html) package.

Comment: profmem does NOT log memory deallocations. All it does is log EACH memory allocation and report each allocation + the total memory allocated. This will not report the max memory used at any point in time by the code which is what I am looking for.

Comment: The community would gladly help you with this follow-up question if you ask it as a new question ([please see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)).  In addition, if you do not think the above answer adequately addresses your original question, please consider clarifying why.